# Reshaping in R: grouping vectors after merge

Tags: r, vector

I have a pretty basic problem that I can't seem to solve:

Take 3 vectors:

| V1 | V2 | V3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | 8 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 |

I want to merge the 3 columns into a single column and assign a group.

Desired result:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| B | 6 |
| C | 7 |
| C | 8 |
| C | 9 |

My code:

```
V1 <- c(1,2,3)
V2 <- c(4,5,6)
V3 <- c(7,8,9)

data <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "C"),
                   values = c(V1, V2, V3))
```

Actual result:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| B | 5 |
| C | 6 |
| A | 7 |
| B | 8 |
| C | 9 |

How can I reshape the data to get the desired result?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `stack` on a named `list` of vectors

```
stack(setNames(mget(paste0("V", 1:3)), LETTERS[1:3]))[2:1]
```

-output

```
ind values
1   A      1
2   A      2
3   A      3
4   B      4
5   B      5
6   B      6
7   C      7
8   C      8
9   C      9
```

---

Regarding the issue in the OP's data creation, if the length is less than the length of the second column, it will recycle.  We may need `rep`

```
data <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), c(length(V1), 
   length(V2), length(V3))),
                   values = c(V1, V2, V3))
```

-output

```
> data
  group values
1     A      1
2     A      2
3     A      3
4     B      4
5     B      5
6     B      6
7     C      7
8     C      8
9     C      9
```

Comment: In my actual workflow the variable names are not V1, V2, V3, but rather more obscure and my columns indeed vary in length, so the first solution wouldn't work for me; however, your 2nd solution using rep() was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @Taurophylax I assumed you have objects createed in the global env and not a data.frame with multiple columns.  If it is a data.frame, you can just do `stack(df1)` and then rename the columns or do the rename first and then stack

Answer (score 1):

Here is a another option using `pivot_longer()` and converting the 1,2,3 column names into factors labeled A, B, C

```
V1 <- c(1,2,3)
V2 <- c(4,5,6)
V3 <- c(7,8,9)
df <- data.frame(V1, V2, V3)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

#basic answer:
answer<-pivot_longer(df, cols=starts_with("V"),  names_to = "Group")
```

**OR**
Answer changing the column names to a different label

```
answer<-pivot_longer(df, cols=starts_with("V"), names_prefix = "V", names_to = "Group")
answer$Group <- factor(answer$Group, labels = c("A", "B", "C")) 
answer %>% arrange(Group, value)
```